# Continuous Sobolev Embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Does Sobolev spaces $H^s$ continuously embed into $L^2$? It seems like this is the case from this post

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space

where can i find a list of continuous sobolev embedding? The only thing I can find is Sobolev embedding theorem, which does cover what I have written here.

Comment: Sure, you just need the inequality $\| f \|_{L^2} \leq C \| f \|_{H^s}$. For integer $s$ this is immediate; for non-integer $s$ you can use the Plancherel theorem straightforwardly. The main Sobolev embedding theorems are about finding the optimal cases (e.g., the maximal $L^q$ such that $W^{1,p}$ is continuously embedded in $L^q$ on a bounded domain).

Comment: @Ian woah, let me digest that. Do you mean for a particular $W^{m,p}$, say, for a fixed $n$, smaller than the particular $1\leq q\leq q^*$ the embedding is continuous?  (where q^* is given by the Sobolev embedding theorem)

Comment: On a bounded domain, $W^{1,p}$ embeds continuously into $L^q$ for all $1 \leq q \leq q^*$. It embeds *compactly* into $L^q$ for all $1 \leq q < q^*$ (this is Rellich's compactness theorem). This fundamentally requires the fact that the domain is bounded, because on an unbounded domain (or more generally an infinite measure space), the $L^p$ spaces do not form a hierarchy.

Comment: @Ian what if the differentiability order is not 1? (I only need a bounded domain, but what about in general?)

Comment: If it's not 1, then you're presumably talking about embedding $W^{k,p}$ into $W^{m,q}$. The important thing is the number of derivatives that you *lose*, which in my notation is $m-k$. Then Sobolev embedding says that you can choose $q \in [1,r]$ where $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{m-k}{n}$.

Comment: @Ian yeah that is what I thought - thanks a bunch, but only on a finite domain?

Comment: On an unbounded domain you are stuck with just embedding $W^{k,p}$ into $W^{m,r}$. You can't choose $q<r$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $H^s$ embeds continuously to $L^2=H^0$ for any $s\geq0$.
(And it fails for all $s<0$. In fact, $H^s$ embeds continuously to $H^r$ whenever $r\leq s$.)

The norm on $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ is (up to a constant that you are free to choose)
$$
\|f\|_{H^s}
=
\|w(\cdot)^s\hat f(\cdot)\|_{L^2},
$$
where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ and $w(x)=(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$.
Since $w(s)^s\geq1$, you have $\|f\|_{H^s}\geq\|f\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the relationship to Sobolev embedding theorem and confirm what I said in the comment for the question is correct?

Comment: @Lost1, you don't need the Sobolev embedding at all to see how $H^s$ embeds to $L^2$. The spaces $H^s$ are $L^2$-based, and Sobolev-embeddings are only needed when you want to compare $W^{k,p}$ with $W^{l,q}$ for $p\neq q$ or with continuous or Hölder spaces. If I understand correctly your comment under the question (which I'm not sure of), this is just $L^p$ embedding to $L^q$ whenever $q\leq p$, as long as we are in a domain of finite measure. So yes, if a space embeds (continuously or compactly) to $L^{q^*}$, then it does so to $L^q$ for any $q\leq q^*$ (over a domain of finite measure).

Comment: I want to know if $W^{k,p}$ goes into $W^{l,q^*}$, what does that say about  $W^{k,p}$  goes into $W^{l,q}$ for $1\leq q \leq q^*$

also does this hold for say $L^p$ and $W^m,p$?

Comment: @Lost1, yes, this works. If $L^p\subset L^q$, then $W^{k,p}\subset W^{k,q}$.